# How to Delete Closed Questions?

Tags: discussion, support

What would happen to closed questions..? (Are they deleted after some period?) I know that we could delete it after 2 days. But what if it has answers, It can't be deleted still..? How would I delete the closed question?

Comment: I think there have been some changes since http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/, but don't have time to run them down just now.

Comment: And, of course, there is http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10582/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed questions are not automatically deleted. They can be deleted by moderators, but we don't generally do that because, honestly, it doesn't seem like the best use of our time.

There are different types of closed questions; in particular, there are questions which are unsuitable in their current form but are close to being fine, and then there are questions which are entirely inappropriate for the site. When we close a question of the first time, we do so with the hope that it will be edited into a form that makes it suitable for reopening. But questions of the second sort, e.g. those that are egregiously off topic or completely nonsensical, we don't hold out much hope for - in other words, once closed, we pretty much expect that they are going to stay closed. Those questions are the ones that would be more appropriate for deletion.